python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully while sam local-deploy
I am trying to local-deploy some lambda function when the build fails and return the following code:
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
**Note1: I have setuptools installed and up to date. 
**Note2: With each lambda I have a requirements file that will install some local and external packages
**Note3: I have the lambda environment set on python3.8 and all the packages I have are compatibly with 3.8

I am trying to local deploy through aws sam and makefile:
project=project make local-deploy

I get:
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

